# L1 norm of (L1 normalized vector minus original vector) less than or equal to 1 minus the L1 norm of the original vector

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

I am reading one paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.09407.pdf). There is one step in the proof of Proposition B.1 that I can't understand. To simplify the notations, I restate the equation as follows where $x,y \in [0, 1]^d$ for some dimension $d$:

$$
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} - y||_1 \leq \big(\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1\big)||x||_1 + ||x-y||_1 \le 1 - ||x||_1 + ||x-y||_1 
$$

The authors said the above step is by triangle inequality, which I believe is by
$$
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} - y||_1 = ||\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x + x - y||_1 \le ||\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x||_1 + ||x - y||_1
$$

However, it seems the authors also utilized
$$
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x||_1 \le \big(\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1\big)||x||_1
$$
which I am not sure why. Is the above inequality always true for any vector within range $[0,1]^d$?

Comment: Looks to me like it's just $ax-x = (a-1)x$. I might be worried about the sign, and think there may need to be $|\cdot|$ instead of $(\cdot)$.

Comment: The right-hand side of my inequality can also be written as $||\frac{||x||_1}{||x||_1} - ||x||_1||_1$. Are you suggesting $||\frac{x}{||x||_1} - x||_1 = ||\frac{||x||_1}{||x||_1} - ||x||_1||_1$, basically replacing $x$ with $||x||_1$ (which does not seem correct to me)? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: No, I am saying exactly what @geetha290krm said. And just as he said, I also suggest you have to worry about the sign of the constant (it will be nonnegative if $\frac{1}{|| x ||}_1 \leq 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} - y||_1 \leq \big(\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1\big)||x||_1 + ||x-y||_1$ is false when $x=y$ and $\|x||_1=2$.

Everything looks fine when $\|x\|_1 \leq 1$. In that case, $
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x||_1 \le \big(\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1\big)||x||_1
$ follows from the fact that $\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x=(\frac 1 {\|x\|_1}-1) x$ and $\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have taken the following steps.
\begin{align*}
||\frac{x}{||x||_1} -x||_1 = ||(\frac{1}{||x||_1} -1)x||_1 = \big|\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1\big| ||x||_1
\end{align*}
but as @MPW already mentioned I can not justify why they have normal brackets around the $\frac{1}{||x||_{1}} - 1$ unless $||x||_1 \leq 1$